# PlayerPrefsX SetColor and GetColor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, cube

I create a cube and button. I want when I click a button change cube color with `PlayerPrefsx`. How to do this?

```
//PlayerPrefsX.SetColor ("PlatformColor");

public class Change6 : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject[] platforms = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("One");

        Color savedBallColor = PlayerPrefsX.GetColor("PColor");
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = savedBallColor;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GameObject[] platforms = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("One");
        Color currentBallColor = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        PlayerPrefsX.SetColor("PColor", currentBallColor);
    }

    public void buttonpressed6() 
    {
        GameObject[] platforms = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("One");

        foreach (GameObject p in platforms){
            p.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PlayerPrefsX` has been [obsolete since Unity 2.1](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/PlayerPrefsx), so I'm not sure why you're using it.

As for saving/loading a color value from `PlayerPrefs`: Colors can be decomposed into three (or four, if you need alpha) floats or ints, which can be directly saved in [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).